# I am trying to run nab to create the pdb file but it isn`t working (AMBER)

Tags: rna-seq, pdb

Here is the input file for nab:

```
molecule m;
m = arna( "gcuucuucuucuucgc" );
putpdb( "lr16.pdb", m, "-wwpdb -nocid -tr");
```

I am trying to run nab to create the pdb file with this command :

```
$AMBERHOME/bin/nab lr16.nab\./a.out
```

But it comes out saying :

```
gcc: error: lr16.nab./a.out: No such file or directory
cc failed!
```

I have loaded the appropriate modules , please could someone help

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about `nab` ... however

```
“$AMBERHOME/bin/nab lr14.nab./a.out”
```

Looking at your error `lr14.nab./a.out:`

It suggests you didn't put a space character between `lr16.nab` and `a.out`. If you run

```
$AMBERHOME/bin/nab lr14.nab ./a.out
```

I suspect it will work because at present it is looking for a file named lr14.nab./a.out which could be interpreted as a directory of `lr14.nab.` and a input file of `a.out` or the error suggests it is reading `/` as part of the file name. `a.out` of course doesn't exist its your specified output file name

---

output of `ls -l`

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 phys 89 Oct 6 12:58 lr14.nab – Peter 5 hours ago
```

Comment: "/nab: lr16.nab: no such file" is what it comes up with now. This is very weird as the instructions tell me to use lr16.nab. Any ideas?

Comment: what does `ls -l`  give you?

Comment: I will check now

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 phys  89 Oct  6 12:58 lr14.nab

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 an909 phys 145 Oct  6 12:59 README

Comment: I've modified my post accordingly. It should work now

Comment: I found out why it wasn’t working , turns out the function I was using doesn’t exist in AMBER! I’ve changed the function and it works ! Sorry for the long time it took me to reply, and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
$AMBERHOME/bin/nab -v lr14.nab -o ./a.out,
```

then execute a.out separately using

```
./a.out.
```

You will get the `pdb` file of nab extension.